# orocos_toolchain install git issue

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install hector_slam on Ubuntu Lucid lynx. For installing orocos_toolchain, I am following instructions on [roswiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/orocos_toolchain_ros). At a intermediate step, i am getting following error:

```
dst:desktop:~/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain$ git submodule update
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/rtt/.git/
 

error: Unable to get pack file https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git/objects/pack/pack-8d2bd25397e5fedbb908340c0536ada28f680d46.pack
Peer closed the TLS connection
error: Unable to find 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76 under https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git
Cannot obtain needed object 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76
while processing commit a03ed29d72bd8eeaa06eb5f5ae3145b26d7026e1.
error: Fetch failed.
Clone of 'https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git' into submodule path 'rtt' failed
```

Can someone tell me cause of this?

**Update1:**

I deleted everything. and start a fresh again. But I am still getting following error.

```
error: Unable to get pack file https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git/objects/pack/pack-8d2bd25397e5fedbb908340c0536ada28f680d46.pack
Peer closed the TLS connection
error: Unable to find 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76 under https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git
Cannot obtain needed object 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76
while processing commit a03ed29d72bd8eeaa06eb5f5ae3145b26d7026e1.
error: Fetch failed.
Clone of 'https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git' into submodule path 'rtt' failed
```

**Update2**: i deleleted everything and started from fresh. Following is the output.

```
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ git clone http://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/orocos_toolchain.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/.git/
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ git clone http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_ros_integration.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/rtt_ros_integration/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 624, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (395/395), done.
remote: Total 624 (delta 392), reused 339 (delta 208)
Receiving objects: 100% (624/624), 97.34 KiB | 38 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (392/392), done.
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ git clone http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_ros_comm.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/rtt_ros_comm/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 22, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (22/22), done.
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ 
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ git clone http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_common_msgs.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/rtt_common_msgs/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 83, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (80/80), done.
remote: Total 83 (delta 48), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (83/83), done.
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ git clone http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_geometry.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/rtt_geometry/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 223, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (219/219), done.
remote: Total 223 (delta 115), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (223/223), 44.48 KiB | 46 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (115/115), done.
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments$ roscd orocos_toolchain
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain$ git submodule init
Submodule 'log4cpp' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/log4cpp.git) registered for path 'log4cpp'
Submodule 'ocl' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/ocl.git) registered for path 'ocl'
Submodule 'orogen' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/orogen.git) registered for path 'orogen'
Submodule 'rtt' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git) registered for path 'rtt'
Submodule 'rtt_gems' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt_gems.git) registered for path 'rtt_gems'
Submodule 'rtt_typelib' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt_typelib.git) registered for path 'rtt_typelib'
Submodule 'typelib' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/typelib.git) registered for path 'typelib'
Submodule 'utilmm' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/utilmm.git) registered for path 'utilmm'
Submodule 'utilrb' (https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/utilrb.git) registered for path 'utilrb'
dst@dst-desktop:~/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain$ git submodule update
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/log4cpp/.git/
Submodule path 'log4cpp': checked out 'b81c6394d68b6d517f70c69605bb93c59391e65a'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/ocl/.git/
Submodule path 'ocl': checked out '15d28f143392983a1de67bc2a6149dbe13117ebb'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/orogen/.git/
Submodule path 'orogen': checked out 'f8bde6648360e04d9887223bd0b6df8df1e55500'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dst/robotics/experiments/orocos_toolchain/rtt/.git/
error: Unable to get pack file https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git/objects/pack/pack-8d2bd25397e5fedbb908340c0536ada28f680d46.pack
Peer closed the TLS connection
error: Unable to find 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76 under https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git
Cannot obtain needed object 526a4adc3102ba0ec72ca1135cecf669e42d1f76
while processing commit a03ed29d72bd8eeaa06eb5f5ae3145b26d7026e1.
error: Fetch failed.
Clone of 'https://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/rtt.git' into submodule path 'rtt' failed
```

stuck! Any alternative to download??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38516/orocos_toolchain-install-git-issue/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-10**:
Perhaps it was a transient error? Just checked here and all seems to work.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-10**:
i had tried thrice over 24 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit after updated question:

Besides the fact that you have a problem with git, I can't find the dependency on OROCOS in `hector_slam` (at least not on its wiki page)?

<s>Also: a deb (binary package) install is not possible?</s> Edit: seems not, as there are (AFAIK) no debs for `orocos_toolchain` on fuerte yet.

> I am sitting behind a proxy but that should not be a problem.

Should not no, but I've seen stranger things happen. The 'Peer closed the TLS connection' bit could point towards your proxy interfering with SSL traffic somehow. As to why the other `git clone` invocations succeed, no idea. A quick Google search shows more people with similar problems (see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gitblit/browse_thread/thread/d6ee8d5d2b98b293/aa37f7751f8949a9) for instance). No solutions that I can find though.

If possible, try without the proxy, to rule out any problems with it.

Alternatively, you could download a zip from gitorious of each of the projects referenced, create the required directory structure by hand and proceed with building.

---

You might also first try updating your git (since you mention being on Lucid): you can use the [Ubuntu Git Maintainers](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core) PPA for that.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-11**:
Please find the update2 in original question. I am sitting behind a proxy but that should not be a problem.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-15**:
OROCOS tool chain is required for hector_quadrotor_controller

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-16**:
Ok, but your original question stated that you were installing 'hector_slam', not the quadrotor_controller. But what is the status of the problem currently? Have you tried without going through the proxy? What about trying to update `git`?